# How to find out if Adobe Flash player is installed, from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash, detect, zeroclipboard

I plan to use [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard) which relies on Adobe Flash player being installed on the user browser. How to find out whether Adobe Flash player is installed from Javascript?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) or:

```
var flash = false;

try {

  if( new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash') ) flash = true;

}catch(e){

  if(navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined) flash = true;

}
```